# Missing mysqli.so file in Centos distribution

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

and in fact I do not have file mysqli.so. This is the content of my /usr/lib64/php/modules directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 16 ago 09.55 .
drwxr-xr-x. 97 root root 8192 30 mar 09.34 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   53  6 nov  2016 bcmath.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   49  6 nov  2016 curl.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   47  6 nov  2016 dom.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   57  6 nov  2016 fileinfo.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   45  6 nov  2016 gd.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   49  6 nov  2016 json.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   57  6 nov  2016 mbstring.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   55  6 nov  2016 mysqlnd.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   69  6 nov  2016 mysqlnd_mysqli.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   67  6 nov  2016 mysqlnd_mysql.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   47  6 nov  2016 pdo.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   63  6 nov  2016 pdo_mysqlnd.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   61  6 nov  2016 pdo_sqlite.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   49  6 nov  2016 phar.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   51  6 nov  2016 posix.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   55  6 nov  2016 sqlite3.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   55  6 nov  2016 sysvmsg.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   55  6 nov  2016 sysvsem.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   55  6 nov  2016 sysvshm.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   49  8 nov  2016 tidy.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   49  6 nov  2016 wddx.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   59  6 nov  2016 xmlreader.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   59  6 nov  2016 xmlwriter.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   47  6 nov  2016 xsl.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   47  6 nov  2016 zip.ini
```

I guess I should chang my php.ini configuration to address an existing file instead of mysqli.so. But why? And what is the reason of this unallignment?

Comment: what's your php version? however it's seems that you need to compile this extension or disable it from that file `mysqlnd_mysqli.ini`

Comment: How do I compile it. And what would be the result of removing it from the ini?